# fragment observe issue

Tags: android, lifecycle, observers

I am facing an issue with LiveData and Fragment Lifecycle.

The flow goes like this:

- The 1st Fragment shows a recyclerview of comments. Each comment has a delete button.
- The 1st Fragment has a menu button, which when pressed, navigates the user to a 2nd Fragment to create a new comment.
- When the user creates the comment, a feedback dialog is shown and `onBackPressed` is called to dismiss the 2nd Fragment.
- The 1st Fragment refreshes the list of comments to show the changes.

Take a look at the code snippets below. The method `observe` is getting called on the Fragment's `onCreateView`.

1st Fragment:

```
private void observe() {
    //getComments method observes the API response from the allComments method
    mainViewModel.getComments().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), resp -> {
        if (resp != null && resp.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("success message");
            builder.setPositiveButton("ΟΚ", (dialog, id) -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });
}
mainViewModel.getCommentDelete().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), resp -> {
        if (resp != null && resp.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("Comment deleted.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("ΟΚ", (dialog, id) -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
            builder.create().show();
            //allComments method makes an http call to the API to fetch comments
            mainViewModel.allComments(mainViewModel.getSelected().getId());
        }
    });

//initView. The adapter has a listener to listen for button clicks.
mAdapter = new BuildingCommentsAdapter(new RecyclerMultipleOptionsClick() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(int position, int id) {
            Comments comment = mAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.comment_save:
                    mainViewModel.commentUpdate(new UpdateCommentReq(mainViewModel.getSelected().getId(), comment.getComment(), comment.getId()));
                    break;
                case R.id.comment_delete:
                    mainViewModel.commentDelete(comment.getId());
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
```

The issue i am facing is:
I run the app and I go to the comment list fragment, I press the `add comment` button and go to 2nd Fragment. Adding a comment and going back. So far so good. Now, I delete one comment from the list (works great). I navigate again to the 2nd Fragment to create a new comment and going back again to the 1st Fragment. The `mainViewModel.getCommentDelete().observe(..)` runs again, showing the success dialog (without deleting something). The problem is that the observer is triggered again and again once I delete one comment from the list.

I can provide more code if you like. Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is LiveData cached your value, and when you comeback to screen you are getting the old value. Should google about SingleLiveData event for navigation purpose.
[Here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) or [here](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8).

Comment: Thanks! event providing only links, at least they were helpful and eventually fixed it